# How to set an expire time to the token in Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

This is the way I generate a token for the user,

```
$token = $user->createToken('app_token')->plainTextToken;
```

Is there any way to automatically expire this token after a certain amount of time? (Which means automatically deleting the token record from personal_access_tokens table)

Comment: The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#token-expiration) states you can do so, but expire for ALL tokens, not a single one. I did not use Sanctum extensively before and I do not have it installed now, so I have no idea if there is a specific method (when creating the token) to just expire that one on a desired amount of time

Comment: @matiaslauriti you are right, since he already is using a table to store all of the tokens, he can further create a scheduler to check for created_at vs when he wants the time to expire, then destroy the token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the expiration configuration option defined in your application's sanctum configuration file.

```
'expiration' => 525600,
```

Token will be considered as expired after this time. if you want to delete that token from the database in that case you have to schedule tasks like this

```
$schedule->command('sanctum:prune-expired --hours=24')->daily();
```

This scheduled task will delete all expired tokens from the database

Comment: Can you mention the file paths too

Comment: Here is the file path app/Console/Kernel.php for scheduling task

Comment: So this will delete the token every 24 hours? What is meant by 'expiration' => 525600,

Comment: That is number of second for which token will be active. if you would like to expiry token after the 24 hours you have to set expiration' => 86400, this will just invalidate your token after 24 hours. if you would like to delete that token from database then you have to set scheduler task mentioned in the answer